# Problems finding vcvarsall.bat when using distutils

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

So this problem started out when I tried building an extension with Cython using the following setup.py script.

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
setup(
cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
ext_modules = [
Extension("program1",["program1.pyx"],),])
```

When I try build it using:
   `python setup.py build` I get the following error:

```
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

I am using the Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler Package for Python 2.7. After a bit a research, some other SO questions led me to believe that my PATH variables weren't properly set.

I set it as follows:

`VS90COMNTOOLS=C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\;`

which is where my vcvarsall.bat file is located. This didn't solve my problem as I was still getting the same error about vcvarsall.bat.
I know there's already a bunch of posts about this particular error already but I still haven't found a solution.

I found [this](http://bugs.python.org/issue23246) discussion specifically about my problem however I don't understand the following steps:

```
1) Enter MSVC for Python command prompt   (how do I do this?)
2) SET DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1
3) SET MSSdk=1
4) python.exe setup.py ...
```

Finally: further down in the discussion Steve proposes to replace the

```
from distutils.core import setup
```

with

```
from setuptools import setup
```

This worked! However now I have a problem, whenever I try to run something that uses distutils setup instead of setuptools, it raises the same "cannot find vcvarsall.bat" problem.
For example, I tried using the IPython magic command

```
%%cython_inline
```

I've been at this for a couple days now and all I want is to properly fix the issue for good, it's been very frustrating.

A patch was made recently which is supposed to fix the issue with finding vcvarsall.bat. You can see that [here](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/src/998c48833975885f36929f42edd13159e3bf9f8a/setuptools/msvc9_support.py?at=default). Do I just run the script/functions inside it? It didn't seem to change anything in my distutils\msvc9compiler.py file.
I hope someone can point me in the right direction here.

Answer (score 1):

There has been further discussions on the python bug tracker [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue23246). It's not an ideal fix but Mark Lawrence suggests a rather simple hack that works. Here's what was suggested:

```
My work around for this was to edit the distutils msvc9compiler.py file.
I commented out the line vcvarsall = find_vcvarsall(version) in the function
query_vcvarsall and hard coded vcvarsall = r'C:\Program Files\Microsoft 
Visual  Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat'. This assumes that you've got a copy of 
Visual C++!:) HTH.
```

The msvc9compiler.py file is located in C:\Python27\Lib\distutils (or somewhere else if you installed Python in a different location than the default). The only change I made is pointing the vcvarsall.bat file to my specific MSVC compiler.

In my case, since I used the Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler Package for Python 2.7 to compile Python, I changed the variable as follows:

```
vcvarsall = 
r'C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for
Python\9.0\vcvarsall.bat' #where .. is my user account name
```

Comment: This answer helped me get passed error: 'unable to fin vcvarsall.bat'. The only difference was I had to edit '_msvccompiler.py'.

Answer (score 1):

From [this message on the Python bug tracker](https://bugs.python.org/issue7511#msg239383)

> The correct solution to this issue now is to install the Microsoft supplied "Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7" package (available as a free download from MSDN). That has all the components needed to build 32 and 64-bit extensions. Your setup.py needs to use setuptools (as there is a setuptools extension to recognise this compiler package) but otherwise the process should be seamless.

Comment: This is correct. My problem was specific to when I was using libraries that still used `from distutils.core import setup`. I was getting errors for some reason.